# Bootstrap Timepicker in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, timepicker

I am new to Angularjs. I have the following directive for bootstrap timepicker.

```
directive('timepicker', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'AC',
        link: function(scope, el, attr)
        {
            if( ! jQuery.isFunction(jQuery.fn.timepicker))
                return false;

            var $this = angular.element(el),

                opts = {
                    template: attrDefault($this, 'template', false),
                    showSeconds: attrDefault($this, 'showSeconds', false),
                    defaultTime: attrDefault($this, 'defaultTime', 'current'),
                    showMeridian: attrDefault($this, 'showMeridian', true),
                    minuteStep: attrDefault($this, 'minuteStep', 15),
                    secondStep: attrDefault($this, 'secondStep', 15)
                },
                $n = $this.next(),
                $p = $this.prev();

            $this.timepicker(opts);

            if($n.is('.input-group-addon') && $n.has('a'))
            {
                $n.on('click', function(ev)
                {
                    ev.preventDefault();

                    $this.timepicker('showWidget');
                });
            }

            if($p.is('.input-group-addon') && $p.has('a'))
            {
                $p.on('click', function(ev)
                {
                    ev.preventDefault();

                    $this.timepicker('showWidget');
                });
            }
        }
    }
}).
```

In my partial Html view, i have the following code,

```
<input type="text" id="start_time" class="form-control timepicker" placeholder="Shift time" name="start_time" data-default-time="data.emp_start_time" ng-model="data.emp_start_time" id="end_time" data-template="dropdown" data-minute-step="5">
     
<input type="text" class="form-control timepicker" placeholder="Shift time" name="end_time" data-default-time="data.emp_end_time" ng-model="data.emp_end_time" data-template="dropdown" data-show-meridian="true" data-minute-step="5" >




<input type="text" id="start_time" class="form-control timepicker" placeholder="Shift time" name="start_time" data-default-time="data.emp_start_time" ng-model="data.emp_start_time" id="end_time" data-template="dropdown" data-minute-step="5">

<input type="text" class="form-control timepicker" placeholder="Shift time" name="end_time" data-default-time="data.emp_end_time" ng-model="data.emp_end_time" data-template="dropdown" data-show-meridian="true" data-minute-step="5" >
```

Here i linked the existing stored time in timepicker. If i wants to edit the shift timimg i have to do. My problem is input controls shows the stored time properly. But timepicker popup shows wrong time(E.g 1:00 PM) always first time. afterwards if we clicks the timepicker its showing the Correct value.

i am using bootstrap-timepicker.min.js.

Whats the problem behind this?

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: For support please provide a working plunker. As alternative you could use https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/timepicker or compare the implementation with yours.